# state.concat redux reducers in angular 6 is not concatenating the payload data?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx-store, reducers, ngrx-reducers

- reducers/index.ts

  ````
  export interface State {
    questionnotifications: QuestionNotification;
  }

  export const reducers = {
    questionnotifications: fromNotification.questionreducer,
  };


  export const getQuestionNotifications = (state: State) => state.questionnotifications;```
  ````
- actions/notification.ts

  ````
  import {Action} from '@ngrx/store';

  export const QUESTIONADD = '[Question] add';
  export const QUESTIONREMOVE = '[Question] remove';



  export class QuestionNotificationAdd implements Action {
    type = QUESTIONADD;

    constructor(public payload: NewQuestionNotification[]) {
    }
  }


  export class QuestionNotificationRemove extends QuestionNotificationAdd {
    type = QUESTIONREMOVE;
    /* constructor(public payload: NewQuestionNotification[]) {}*/
  }```
  ````
- models/notification.ts

```
export interface QuestionNotification {
   doctor_id_c: string;
   pat_image: string;
   pat_name: string;
   patient_id_c: string;
   q_id: number;

 }

 export class NewQuestionNotification implements QuestionNotification {
   doctor_id_c: string;
   pat_image: string;
   pat_name: string;
   patient_id_c: string;
   q_id: number;

   constructor(doctor_id_c: string, pat_image: string, pat_name: string, patient_id_c: string, q_id: number) {
     this.doctor_id_c = doctor_id_c;
     this.pat_image = pat_image;
     this.pat_name = pat_name;
     this.patient_id_c = patient_id_c;
     this.q_id = q_id;
   }}
```

- reducers/notifications.ts

```
  export function questionreducer(state = [], action: notification.QuestionNotificationAdd) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case notification.QUESTIONADD:
        return state.concat(action.payload).filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
          return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj['q_id']).indexOf(obj['q_id']) === pos;
        });

      case notification.QUESTIONREMOVE:
        console.log('in remove question notification');
        console.log(action.payload[0].q_id);
        return state.filter(function (el) {
          return el.q_id != action.payload[0].q_id;
        });

      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

We are generating notifications in angular 6, browser is receiving the fcm notifications the same notifications payload data we are trying to store in redux state but we are  facing a problem while displaying the redux stored data because the payload data is not concatenating with redux state data.

Kindly advice where we are going wrong.

Comment: If there is a problem, it doesn't come from the `concat`. But probably more from `filter`

Comment: even after removing the filter, its not working.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you use `questionreducer` please

Comment: this.store.dispatch(new QuestionNotificationAdd([new NewQuestionNotification('13', 'image', 'C', '928', 3)]));

Comment: Update your code with this information **AND** also where you import your reducer.

Comment: We have already imported the reducers in index.ts file and using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

How about we start by making that code a bit more readable?

```
     case notification.QUESTIONADD:
        const withDuplicates = state.concat(action.payload)
        const ids = withDuplicates.map(n => n.q_id)
        const withoutDuplicates = withDuplicates.filter((o, i) => ids.indexOf(o.q_id) === i)
        return withoutDuplicates
```

Comment: What are the ouputs when you console.log(state) and console.log(action.payload)?

Comment: console.log(state) = [Object][Object]
console.log(action.payload) = [Object][Object]

Comment: Do a console.log(JSON.stringify(state)) and payload then please.